# PrincipicalContext ActiveDirectory validating a user in a container

Tags: c#, validation, ldap

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"domain","CN=GroupName, DC = domainc, DC = local")) 
{
    // validate the credentials
    try
    {
        bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("userName", "password");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

In the PrincipialContext constructor if I only put in the domain name I am able to validate the user. If I however put in CN="BadGroupNameDoesNotExist" it still validates the user as true. It seems it doesn't matter what I put in for the CN.

Why is that? I am new to active directory and thought putting in a valid CN would have valid credentials only if he belonged to that group but that appears not true?

Comment: you do not need to pass in the CN like you are doing I will post something that I am currently doing that works in regards to validating a user in AD

Answer (score 0):

you could try creating a utils class and adding the following methods etc..

```
using System.Security;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
public struct Credentials
{
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
}
public class Domain_Authentication
{
    public Credentials Credentials;
    public string Domain;
    public Domain_Authentication(string Username, string Password, string SDomain)
    {
        Credentials.Username = Username;
        Credentials.Password = Password;
        Domain = SDomain;
    }
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain))
        {
            // validate the credentials
            return pc.ValidateCredentials(Credentials.Username, Credentials.Password);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I have it return true if only the user belonged to a certain group?

Comment: you could use `GroupPrincipal` inside of the using for example `GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, "YourGroupName");` then you can  Search through the group.Members property until you have a Principal that you want.

Comment: example `foreach (Principal prnc in group.Members)`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that `ValidateCredentials` pays no attention to the container name/OU.

Both of the **Remarks** sections in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.validatecredentials?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalContext_ValidateCredentials_System_String_System_String_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_ContextOptions_) include

> The ValidateCredentials method binds to the server specified in the constructor.

There is no mention of the container specified in the constructor being used, and as you have discovered it is not checked either.